# Convert ngrams count files into ARPA format

Tags: speech-recognition, n-gram, language-model, srilm

I want to convert all my n-grams files into one [ARPA](https://web.archive.org/web/20200215083618/http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu:80/Speech/docs/HTKBook3.2/node213_mn.html) file. It will be used as a Language Model for speech recognition.

I have different n-grams files, 2-grams, 3-grams and 4-grams. Taking 2-grams file as example

`two grams -- frequency similar degree  32 Writing writes  1 towars their    3 country feature 1 like gold   446 like golf   64`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In srilm package the command to convert counts to arpa is:

```
  ngram-count -read file.counts -lm file.lm
```

When doing that you need just maximum order count file, 2-grams are not needed because lower order counts are recomputed from high-order counts.

[Here](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ngram-count.1.html) you can find detailed documentation for ngram-count.